# Function to count hashtags

Tags: python, regex, string, counting

I'm trying to get a function that counts and shows hashtags of a list.

Example input:

```
["Hey, im in the #pool",
 "beautiful #city",
 "#city is nice",
 "Have a nice #weekend",
 "#weekend <3",
 "Nice #"]
```

Output:

```
{"pool" : 1, "city" : 2, "weekend" : 2}
```

But if there is only a `#` followed by no words, it should not count as a hashtag. 
Same with stuff before the hashtag, something like „%#“ is not allowed to count as a hashtag.
Hashtags are defined (a-z,A-Z,0-9) every other char ends the hashtag

My current code:

```
def analyze(posts):
    tag = {}
    for sentence in posts:
        words = sentence.split(' ')
        for word in words:
            if word.startswith('#'):
                if word[1:] in tag.keys():
                    tag[word[1:]] += 1
                else:
                    tag[word[1:]] = 1
    return(tag)


posts = ["Hey, im in the #pool",
         "beautiful #city",
         "#city is nice",
         "Have a nice #weekend",
         "#weekend <3",
         "Nice #"]
print(analyze(posts))
```

Comment: Did *any* of the answers provide the expected output?

Comment: Looks like this is a task from some programming contest. Here is the same question: [Hashtag counter Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58500592/7851470)

Answer (score 9):

In one pass with *case insensitive* regex search and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

lst = ["Hey, im in the #pool", "beautiful #city", "#city is nice",
       "Have a nice #weekend", "#weekend <3", "Nice #"]

hash_counts = Counter(re.findall(r'#([a-z0-9]+)', ' '.join(lst), re.I))
print(dict(hash_counts))
```

The output:

```
{'pool': 1, 'city': 2, 'weekend': 2}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `re` with `collections.Counter` :

```
import re
from collections import Counter

data  = [ "Hey, im in the #pool",
  "beautiful #city",
  "#city is nice",
  "Have a nice #weekend",
  "#weekend <3",
  "Nice #" ]

count_hashtag = Counter()
for element in data:
    for hast_tag in re.findall('#(\w+)', element):
        count_hashtag[hast_tag] += 1

print(count_hashtag)
# Counter({'city': 2, 'weekend': 2, 'pool': 1})
```

If you want `#City` and `#city` equal:

```
  count_hashtag[hast_tag.casefold()] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
a = [ "Hey, im in the #pool",
  "beautiful #city",
  "#city is nice",
  "Have a nice #weekend",
  "#weekend <3",
  "Nice #"]
resdict = {}
for item in a:
    for word in item.split():
        if word.startswith('#') and len(word) != 1:
            if word.replace('#', '') not in resdict:
                resdict[word.replace('#', '')] = 1
            else: resdict[word.replace('#', '')] += 1
print(resdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ["Hey, im in the #pool",
 "beautiful #city",
 "#city is nice",
 "Have a nice #weekend",
 "#weekend <3",
 "Nice #"]


from collections import defaultdict 
def func(l):

    dic = defaultdict(int)
    for i in l:
        for j in i.split():
            if j[0]=='#' and len(j)>1:
                dic[j[1:]]+=1
    return dict(dic)

print(func(l))
```

output

```
{'pool': 1, 'city': 2, 'weekend': 2}
```