# Hashtag counter Python

Tags: python

I am a python beginner. For an exercise, I have to write a python function that will scan a list of strings, counts how many times a hashtag appears and puts this into a dictionary. Example:

```
[
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #zurich #limmat",
    "spend my #weekend in #zurich",
    "#zurich <3"
]
```

After analyzing this list, the function should return:

`{'weekend': 2, 'zurich': 3, 'limmat': 1}`

Only letters and numbers are allowed, anything else, like spaces and periods, end the hashtag.

We can assume that the parameter is always a valid list of strings and you do not need to provide any kind of input validation.

Hashtags are case-specific. `#ZURICH` should be counted as a different hashtag than `#zurich`.

---

I have an ugly first draft of a function, that doesn't work if there are more than one hashtags in a string, as it will skip the second one. I don't necessarily need tipps on how to simplify the function or make it more pythonic (though of course it would still be appreciated). I just want to know why it doesn't work.

---

```
def analyze(posts):
    hashtag_dict = {}
    for post_string in posts:
        for char in post_string:
            if char == "#":
                hash_index = post_string.find(char)
                counter = 1
                tag = ""
                for tag_char in post_string[hash_index + 1:]:
                    if tag_char.isdigit() or tag_char.isalpha():
                        tag += tag_char
                    elif tag in hashtag_dict:
                        counter += 1
                        hashtag_dict[tag] = counter
                        break
                    else:
                        hashtag_dict[tag] = counter
                        break
    return hashtag_dict


posts = [
        "hi #weekend",
        "good morning #zurich #limmat",
        "spend my #weekend in #zurich",
        "#zurich <3"]

print(analyze(posts))
```

---

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try reading on `regular expressions`. I think that can solve your problem in just a handful of lines.

Comment: This Regex will find your hashtag values and then you can count them `\#([^ ]+)` as will find "anything but spaces"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to count hashtags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485274/function-to-count-hashtags)

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, your function doesn’t work because this line

```
hash_index = post_string.find(char)
```

Will always find the index of the *first* hash tag in the string. This could be fixed by providing a [start index to `str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), or, better, by not calling `str.find` at all and instead maintaining the index when iterating over the string (you can use `enumerate` for that). Better yet, don’t use an index, you don’t need it if you restructure your parser to use a state machine.

That said, a Pythonic implementation would replace the whole function with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), which would make it drastically shorter, correct, more readable, and likely more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I assume it is expected of us to do the exercise using only what we've learned in the course so far. We didn't get into regular expressions yet. I'll try to fix it with your suggestions tho!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import string
alpha = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def analyze(posts):
    hashtag_dict = {}

    for post in posts:
        for i in post.split():
            if i[0] == '#':
                current_hashtag = sanitize(i[1:])

                if len(current_hashtag) > 0:
                    if current_hashtag in hashtag_dict:
                        hashtag_dict[current_hashtag] += 1
                    else:
                        hashtag_dict[current_hashtag] = 1

    return hashtag_dict


def sanitize(s):
    s2 = ''
    for i in s:
        if i in alpha:
            s2 += i
        else:
            break
    return s2


posts = [
        "hi #weekend",
        "good morning #zurich #limmat",
        "spend my #weekend in #zurich",
        "#zurich <3",
        "#lindehof4Ever(lol)"
        ]

print(analyze(posts))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to work in some cases. However, anything but numbers or letters should end the hashtag. So if someone would write like #zurich(in switzerland) the hashtag should only be "zurich" and not "zurich(in" or whatever. Also empty hashtags should not be in the dictionary. If someone simply writes "#" no entry should be made at all.

Comment: Hm ok we can add conditions for that thought I'm not sure it's best practice

Comment: @Kajice this should work as intended now and also make sure that we only select tags (i.e. if you have ```he#lo``` it now won't be recognized as a tag

Answer (score 1):

Well,

this task can be done with regexes, don't be afraid to use them ;)
Some quick solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(r'#(\w+)')
posts = [
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #zurich #limmat",
    "spend my #weekend in #zurich",
    "#zurich <3"]

container = {}
for post in posts:
    for element in PATTERN.findall(elements):
        container[element] = container.get(element, 0) + 1
print(container)
```

Result:

```
{'zurich': 3, 'limmat': 1, 'weekend': 2}
```

### EDIT

I would like to use here Counter from collections aswell.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import re
from collections import Counter

PATTERN = re.compile(r'#(\w+)')
posts = [
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #zurich #limmat",
    "spend my #weekend in #zurich",
    "#zurich <3"]

words = [word for post in posts for word in PATTERN.findall(post)]

counted = Counter(words)
print(counted)

# Result: Counter({'zurich': 3, 'weekend': 2, 'limmat': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

With your help, I managed to get 2.75 points out of 4. Thanks a lot! I didn't copy-paste any of your solutions into the correction tool, I used my own version that I tried to improve with your suggestions. (I am sure if I posted any of your solutions I would've gotten 4/4.)

According to them, the official solution would have been:

```
def analyze(posts):
tags = {}

for post in posts:
    curHashtag = None
    for c in post:
        is_allowed_char = c.isalnum()

        if curHashtag != None and not is_allowed_char:
            if len(curHashtag) > 0 and not curHashtag[0].isdigit():
                if curHashtag in tags.keys():
                    tags[curHashtag] += 1
                else:
                    tags[curHashtag] = 1
            curHashtag = None

        if c == "#":
            curHashtag = ""
            continue

        if c.isalnum() and curHashtag != None:
            curHashtag += c

    if curHashtag != None:
        if len(curHashtag) > 0 and not curHashtag[0].isdigit():
            if curHashtag in tags.keys():
                tags[curHashtag] += 1
            else:
                tags[curHashtag] = 1

return tags
```

---

This is of course not an elegant solution, but a solution using exclusively what we have learned so far. Maybe this helps another beginner, who wants to use the tools they have to solve this exercise.